# How to add top right save button nav bar in content page xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, content-pages

I have a form page with many fields after editing user have to scroll down all the way down to click save button. Which seems like not user friendly experience i want to move that button at top right position in content page. SO far i found a thing name ToolBarItems in which i can add button but this not helped.

Comment: If the ToolbarItem is not being displayed, try putting your ContentPage inside a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding a `ToolbarItem` to your page. You can do this in *Xaml* like so:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Name="Menu1" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
  <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Or if you prefer *code behind* that can also be done like so:

```
page.ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem (....));
```

**Ref:** http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=232